# Running commands all at once throws error while running commands one after another is ok

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I created a chaincode and deployed it on [the test network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network). I call the transactions from command line.

```
peer chaincode invoke -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"function":"createStore","Args":["1","Target","Weyburn","false"]}'
peer chaincode invoke -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"function":"createCashDesk","Args":["1","1","false"]}'
peer chaincode invoke -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"function":"openStore","Args":["1"]}'
peer chaincode invoke -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"function":"openCashDesk","Args":["1"]}'
```

If I run the four commands all at once, by joinning them with "&", the last command throws error.

If I run the commands one after another, by waiting a few seconds and until I see the command output, all commands run without error.

How would I debug this issue?

I suspect there are some synchronization or mining issues. Is it possible that when the third command returns and outputs, the data are not fully synchronized so that the fourth command goes into a bad state and then faills?

When I was developing Ethereum chaincode, I need to have another terminal open and continuously mine new blocks to commit Ethereum chaincode calls.

In Hyperledger Fabric, how do I stop mining so that transaction requeses are kept pending in the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding `--waitForEvent` to each of the invoke commands otherwise you aren't waiting for the transaction to be committed to the ledger, so subsequent invokes may not see the results of previous invokes

Answer (score 1):

You should post the error.

In this case, I suppose that you are trying to read some value that has not been committed yet. While a block is not committed, the world state is not updated. Thus, the transactions embedded into the block are not updated in the world state. The execution has been simulated, but the world state has not been updated. Thus, you are trying to read a value that does not exist yet.

You can wait the transaction to be committed before the next operation concerning the same document. With NodeJS SDK, this is performed this way: https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/tutorial-transaction-commit-events.html.

`peer` command is only for "playing". Not totally sure, but I think that when `peer` command returns, the transaction has been already committed. But you are launching commands in background with `&`, so you are not waiting for commands to return.

Another related error may be `MVCC_READ_CONFLICT` regarding transactions over the same documents in the same block. The document may exist, but your peers detect the version mismatch in the readsets/writesets when trying to commit and return an error.

### EDIT

To give a quick solution, as david_k suggests specify `--waitForEvent` and concatenate commands with `&&`, not `&`. Anyway, take always into account what I've told you before.

Comment: Thanks for your other suggestions!